# pd.to_datetime to solve '2010/1/1' rather than '2010/01/01'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which contain a column 'trade_dt' like this

```
2009/12/1
2009/12/2
2009/12/3
2009/12/4
```

I got this problem

```
benchmark['trade_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(benchmark['trade_dt'], format='%Y-&m-%d')

ValueError: time data '2009/12/1' does not match format '%Y-&m-%d' (match)
```

how to solve it? Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Need change [`format`](http://strftime.org/) for match - replace `&` and `-` to `%` and `/`:

```
benchmark['trade_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(benchmark['trade_dt'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Also working with sample data removing `format` (but not sure with real data):

```
benchmark['trade_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(benchmark['trade_dt'])

print (benchmark)
    trade_dt
0 2009-12-01
1 2009-12-02
2 2009-12-03
3 2009-12-04
```

Comment: I got a terrible mistake! Just replace & to % is ok. Thank you very much